# Cómo agrego un título o membrete a un csv?

Tags: php, csv

Yo genero un csv con sus columnas y todo pero necesito colocarle un título/membrete.

```
        $fp = fopen('php://temp','r+');
        $rows = array(
            'Fecha;Nombre;Apellido;Monto Neto;Total;',
        );
        fputcsv($fp,$rows);

        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($event['date'])); // convierto fecha
            $data = array(
                $newDate, //Fecha
                $event['name'], // Nombre
                $event['lastname'], // Apellido
                '$'.$event['net_ammount'], // Monto Neto
                '$'.$event['total_ammount'], // Total
            );
            $rows[] = implode(';', $data);
        }

        $content = implode("\n", $rows);
        $response = new Response($content);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="report.csv"');
```

Es decir, necesitaría colocar el título "REPORTE DEL MES" como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes hacer eso con csv porque los csv no permiten diseño, en todo caso genera un excel con html y php con cabeceras

Comment: Me parece que en un archivo .csv no vas a lograrlo porque  es un formato de solo texto.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *"Como se ve en la imagen"*? Considera que algunos podríamos "verlo" desde una perspectiva distinta a la tuya.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich el motivo no es porque sea un formato de solo texto, por ejemplo HTML también se escribe en un fichero de texto, pero sí se pueden dar estilos. Si en HTML pones `<b>reporte</b>` el navegador va a interpretarlo como texto en negrita. Sin embargo si esto lo haces en un CSV, el programa que lo abra puede que lo sepa reconocer o puede que no. En principio no está obligado a entenderlo si está cumpliendo el estándar de CSV. El problema es que si distribuyes ese CSV y otra persona lo abre con un programa diferente puede que no vea el contenido adecuadamente.

Comment: @Ordago, con formato texto quise decir sin incluir diseños o estilos que  pueda ser reconocido por el  Excel o software similar. Es totalmente  valido tu comentario y concuerdo contigo.

Comment: Gracias a todos. Al final me decante por armar un pdf

Answer (score 1):

La especificación de CSV no admite ningún tipo de estilo: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Si necesitas que el fichero que generes tenga algún tipo de estilo, negrita, unir columnas, etc. lo puedes hacer generando algún tipo de fichero compatible con Excel (.xls, .xlsx, etc.)